# How lumen validates jwt token?

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, lumen, jwt

How *lumen(5.5)* validates `jwt` tokens without storing it in database?.Is it validates by using session?

Answer (score 1):

Lumen does not use sessions.
JWT tokens are stateless, which means they contain the information necessary to identify a user. The is no need to store them.
In my app :
I make login request using my credentials (email , password) , Lumen (checks credentials in database) sends me back generated token (most probably encoding these credentials) and every further request I make I use token (in http header) so Lumen can validate token/user using only token I send in header

Comment: Thank you for your info. I need to know how it validates username and password. <blink> $credentials = $request->only(['username','password']); $credentials['username'] = strtolower(trim($credentials['username'])); $TTL = config('constants.JWT_Token_Expires_limit'); //minutes $this->jwt->factory()->setTTL($TTL); $token = $this->jwt->attempt($credentials); $userPrivilege = Auth::user(); </blink>